# I want to change the theme of my whole application

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to change *Theme* of my application on `button` click. I have defined an `onClick()` function  in my `Activity`.

My code:

```
public class Screen2 extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);
}

public void theme(View view){       
    getApplication().setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
}
```

It doesn't work. Could you please help me to change theme of my application?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I you read android documentation `setTheme()` has to be called only before `setContentView()`. It can't be done after that. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29

Comment: it means we can not change theme of whole app' activity dynamically on button click except only individual activity please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/ramkiranworks/customization/Themes.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) is the nice tutorial for changing the theme on `Button click`

and also [Here](http://www.therealjoshua.com/2012/01/styling-android-with-defaults/) is the tutorial for the Styling Android With Defaults

Comment: This tutorial has the obvious flaw of having to restart the activity that's being changed. This is very problematic if you are trying to keep the whole stack of activities intact. However, knowing this limitations everything works as expected :)

Comment: @Ram thanks for help but i want to change theme of all activity in my app on button click i have given two button if user click on on button it change the current theme of all activity i have used switch statement help me please ...............

Comment: just wait i will upload source code in my blog and send u the url

Comment: click this link https://sites.google.com/site/ramkiranworks/customization/Themes.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: @Ram its shows an error "Unable to resolve target 'android-3" i am new to android how to solve this problem i m using android-15

Comment: ok its common error. If you got like that just clean project in eclipse and change the minsdkversion to 8 in manifest file and change android target by right click on the project

Comment: @Ramkiran thanks its working now. can it possible that i change the theme that make change in all activity's theme in the app even we navigate to several activities.

Comment: just put this line Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this); before setcontentView(R.layout.###) in all your activities. so when you apply it to your main activity it gets appliead to all other actovoties.